# how to calculate the area of $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}+x_3=4 , 0\leq x_3\}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate the area of $$S=\left\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}:x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}+x_3=4 ,\, 0\leq x_3\right\rbrace$$

I think the difficulty(for me) is to parametrize this function. I thought that it would be smart to say that $x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}=4-x_3$ so I can get my parametrisation in a form of a circle-parametrization(though I see that the graph is a cone).

But then i think i get trouble with my $x_3$.

I think I am supposed to get something like: $x_1 = r\cos(\phi)$, $x_2 = r\sin(\phi)$, $x_3 = 4-r^{2}$

But when I calculate the area of this parametrisation I don't get the right answer so I'm doing something wrong.

Any hints,tricks?

Kees

Comment: I'd suggest starting by noting what the possible values for $x_1,x_2$ are. From there, a global map (patch?) can be ascertained.

Comment: Do you get the right answer with your correction? (Note: This is a paraboloid, not a cone.)

Comment: Is this in the context of multivariable calculus?

Comment: @Fantini, yes it is.

Comment: @Braindead, yes i did eventually. I forgot to use the fact that $x_1^{2}+x_2^{2} = r^{2}$ so that made it easy to construct my 'new' $x_3$. thanks for the solutuion with single variable calculus though it learns me to see how this problem can be solved with other methods :)

Comment: I was planning to write a response once I get back (need to leave now). Would you still like me to do it?

Comment: you can do it if you please to, i'm curious to see if you get the same answer as i did :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is a method from single variable calculus that you can use. The surface you are given is a [Surface of Revolution.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html)

In fact, it is exactly what you obtain by taking the graph of the parabola $y = 4 - x^2$ on the $xy$-plane and revolving it around the $y$-axis.

If you do this, $y$ becomes $x_3$ in your problem.

The formula for the surface area of such an object is found in the link given above. You just need to use the correct bounds of integration.

The way I have things set up, it would be correct to use

$\displaystyle\int_c^d 2\pi x \sqrt{1 + \left(\dfrac{dx}{dy}\right)^2} dy$

which is equation (6) or (7) in the link. I would personally use a slight variant:

$\displaystyle\int_a^b 2\pi x \sqrt{1 + \left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx$

I can provide a more detailed answer if you'd like. Just let me know.